# extract block issue preupgradecheck

Tags: powershell

I run an stsadm -o preupgradecheck in ps1 file

```
 function test (){
try{
$cmd=stsadm -o preupgradecheck

}
catch{
Write-host -ForegroundColor Red ($_.Exception.Message)
}

}
test
```

I wander how can I extract the htm file that details information about the installation and any problems found in other file .
and how can I color the output information:
warning in yellow , passed in green and so  ...
beast regards